# What do bl_undo_group and bl_translation_context properties do?

Tags: python, properties, operator

Both Operator and Macro struct's have the properties:

[bl_undo_group](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=bl_undo_group#bpy.types.Operator.bl_undo_group)

[bl_translation_context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=bl_undo_group#bpy.types.Operator.bl_undo_group)

Other than being string values no other information seems available for these properties.

Can anyone explain what these properties do?